# How to read config values in PHP controller?

Tags: php, symfony4

I am using symfony 4.2 framework in which there is PHP controller with multiple actions. I have set below values in packages\config.yaml.

```
myDir: '/abc'
```

I have below controller with 2 actions as defined below.

```
//this works
public function uploadTestAction(Request $r_request)
        {
            $myDir    = $r_request->request->get("myDir");
        }

//this doesn't work
public function loadTestAction(Request $r_request)
        {
            $myDir    = $r_request->request->get("myDir");
            //$myDir    = $r_request->query->get("myDir"); //this is also not working

        }
```

Issue here is I am able to get the value in uploadTestAction but value is coming as null in uploadTestAction. I have tried using query as well but still not getting the correct value. Both request types are GET. What I am missing here or how can trace it ?

Comment: I guess that, you have GET parameter for first action, but have not for the second.

Answer (score 1):

you should define it as parameter:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/parameters.html

```
 final class XyController extends SymfonyController {
     public function registerAction() {
         $dir = $this->container->getParameter('dir');
     }
  }
```